# How do I get a random BigInt in a specific range (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, encryption, cryptography, largenumber

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before but I cannot find any solution that helps me.

Basically, I have a huge number `n` where `n` is a 4000 bit number. Obviously, it won't fit in the 64 bits allowed by the primitive type `int` in Dart.

I need to find a random number `g` such that `2 ≤ g ≤ (n - 1)`. Is there a way I can generate such a random number?

My current solution:

```dart
void _generatePrivateKey() {
  const numbers = '0123456789';
  final halfOfNLength = N.toString().length ~/ 2; // Where `N` is `BigInt`
  final length = _rand.nextInt(halfOfNLength) + halfOfNLength;
  final buffer = StringBuffer();
  for (var _ = 0; _ < length; _++) {
    buffer.write(numbers[_rand.nextInt(numbers.length)]);
  }
  _privateKey = BigInt.parse(buffer.toString());
}
```

I know it's not a good solution but that's all I have for now

Comment: Perhaps this [`randomBigInt()`](https://github.com/ninja-dart/prime/blob/master/lib/ninja_prime.dart#L21) implementation in conjunction with the [`Random.secure`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-math/Random-class.html) constructor could be a starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`package:pointycastle`](https://pub.dev/packages/pointycastle) contains a utility file with a [`decodeBigInt`](https://github.com/bcgit/pc-dart/blob/master/lib/src/utils.dart#L19) function that converts a list of bytes into a [`BigInt`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/BigInt-class.html).

Here's how you can use it to generate a 4000 bit value:

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';

BigInt randomBigInt() {
  const size = 4000;
  final random = Random.secure();
  final builder = BytesBuilder();
  for (var i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    builder.addByte(random.nextInt(256));
  }
  final bytes = builder.toBytes();
  return decodeBigInt(bytes);
}
```

Alternatively, `decodeBigIntWithSign` can be used to enforce a negative or positive result.

Comment: Thank you for your response. My current solution is using [ninja_prime's](https://pub.dev/packages/ninja_prime) method `randomPrimeBigInt` which takes in a `bytes` argument. It generates a prime number but that's better since I need a prime number anyways since I am using said number for cryptology.